# Stop igraph::triad.census returning negative values

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I know that `igraph`'s `triad.census` will arbitrarily return a negative value for the first triad (003) if its incidence is particularly high. Take, for example:

```
library(igraph)
gr <-  erdos.renyi.game(10000, 0.001, directed = T)
triad.census(gr)
# [1] -1164826850   991152717      468094      494363      494021      987907         920         889         969
# [10]         307
```

How can I avoid this behaviour and get the actual incidence of the (first) triad? (I am pretty sure that `abs(triad.census(gr))` is not the solution.)

Comment: Seems like it might be an integer overflow problem. Probably more appropriate to report the problem on the [github issues](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues).

Comment: I did just that, thanks @MrFlick